# Linked List implementation of Stack Deletion Error Using Pop

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, stack

Guys I am a newbie and i am learning data structures.I am learning Linked list implementation of stack and I wrote this code below for the implementation.
the push method works fine but the pop method doesnt works fine and doesnt deletes the node.

```
public class Slink {
    Node head;
    public void push(int data)
    {
        Node node =new Node();
        node.data=data;
        node.next=null;
        if(head==null)
        {
            head=node;

        }
        else
        {
            Node n=head;
            while (n.next!=null)
            {
                n=n.next;
            }
            n.next=node;
        }

    }
    public void pop()
    {
        if(head==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Stack has 0 items .. cant delete");
        }
        else {
            Node n = head;
            while (n.next != null) {
                n = n.next;
            }
            n=null;


        }
    }
    public void show()
    {
        Node n=head;
        while(n.next!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(n.data);
            n=n.next;
        }
        System.out.println(n.data);
    }
}
```

Now using this in a class.

```
public class Sll {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Slink stk=new Slink();
        stk.push(4);
        stk.push(54);

        stk.push(23);
        stk.push(90);

        stk.pop();

        stk.show();

    }
}
```

The output is 
4
54
23
90

while 90 should have been removed.
Guys please tell me where i am wrong and correct me.
Thanks

Comment: why so , if i put n=0 then it modifies the value as 0 then why setting null has a problem

Answer (score 1):

`n=null;` in your `pop()` method modifies nothing else than the value of your scoped `n` variable. You will instead want to set `n.next=null` on the last node which has a non-null next.

It can be done in the following way for example :

```
public void pop()
{
    if(head==null)
    {
        System.out.println("Stack has 0 items .. cant delete");
    }
    else if(head.next == null) {
        head = null;
    }
    else {
        Node n = head;
        while (n.next != null && n.next.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next=null;
    }
}
```

You can try it [here](https://ideone.com/joOYh7). (I've also fixed your `show()` method to work correctly with empty stacks)

Comment: why so , if i put n=0 then it modifies the value as 0 then why setting null has a problem

Comment: and how is thing going to delete the head node ??

Comment: `n` holds the reference to the `Node`. If you do `n.next=0` you're modifying a field of that node, which impacts all references to that node. If you do `n=new Node()` or `n=null` you're just changing the reference (rather than the object it refers to)

Comment: I've fixed the head-popping behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In pop method instead of:

```
Node n = head;
while (n.next != null) {
    n = n.next;
}
n=null;
```

Try:

```
head = head.next();
```

Comment: i am deleting from the end my dear.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you did not mention your node(), class. It seems that you didn't make tail node which is necessary for the link list.
I think this code will definitely help you

**Pop() method**

```
 public void pop() {
    node current = header;
    node back = null;
    while ((current != null)) {
        if ((current == tail)) {
            back.next = null;
            tail = back;
            break;
        }
        else {
            back = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
```

**Node Class**

class node {

```
public int data;

public node next;

public node(int data) {
    this.data = this.data;
    this.next = null;
}
}
```

*Do some changes in **Push method***

```
public void push(int data) {
    node nnew = new node(data);
    if ((header == null)) {
        header = nnew;
        tail = nnew;
    }
    else {
        tail.next = nnew;
        tail = tail.next;
    }
    }
```